# android - hide recyclerview if search is not made

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, searchview

I'm using Searchview to filter through firebase entries displayed in a Recyclerview. I want the Recyclerview to be gone when a search is not made, which is working fine until I go back from the the searched item to the main activity. The recyclerview list is visible again after a search is complete. I want it to always be hidden whenever a search is not made. Here is the relevant code:

```
    msearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String mQuery) {


            /*while (query.length() > 4) {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } */

            if (!(mQuery == null || mQuery.trim().isEmpty())) {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            else {
                mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }

            firebaseSearch(mQuery);

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

            //filter as typed
            firebaseSearch(newText);
            return true;
        }
    });

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's imagine that you have 2 activities: A and B.

After you click on item on activity A, you go to activity B, but this time, acitivity A is not completely destroyed. So the state of input text and recylcerView will remain. After you go back from activity B to activity A, you better perform following action to clear the search view:

```
msearchView.setQuery("",false);
msearchView.setIconified(true);
```

Since the searchView is cleared, onQueryTextChange() will be executed. You can check the condition here.

Comment: Please see the edited code for a better idea of what might be the problem.

Comment: not working. Where exactly in the above code would you call this?

Comment: Please put the log into public `boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)` function, to check if this function is called when you go back to activity 1 from activity 2.

Comment: Got it. Had to add it to onClick and onLongClick as well, with the visibility for the Recyclerview set to gone right after. But it works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider, I think that just checking `query != null` might not always be correct. It might be empty or in theory blank. I would personally use something like:

```
if (query == null || query.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // No query made
}
```

Next, it's possible I didn't quite understand, I believe you have Activity A where the user searches. Once they search you show the recycler view. Then they click on an item and you jump to Activity B. When the user navigates back to A, the list is still full. If this is right you have to remember that A isn't necessarily destroyed when B is visible on top of it. If the phone you're on has low memory the OS might call `onDestroy` and have to recreate it when you navigate back. Anyway... a simple fix here is to hide the RecycleView when you navigate to B.

Comment: I just want that the whole list of entries does not show up on the main page, only when a search is submitted that relevant entries show up (if "be" is typed only the entries that start with "be"), which happens fine when I go from Activity A to B, but not in the other way around. I'll give that a try, how would I refer to the navigation for the condition?

Comment: Also, even if I don't go to Activity B, a submission of a search is enough to make all the entries display.